# How to make the other bars visible in flot graph if the number of data and ticks is maximum?

Tags: javascript

```
 xaxis:{
        min: -1,
        max:50,
        mode:null,
        ticks:[more data to be displayed (more then 500 guess)]
}
```

how to display the other bars since i have specified the maximum as 40 it is showing only 40 bars but there are around 500 bars, i want to display them all .. I am using flot.js java script plugin.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: it is not a kind of framework where as it is ordinary html css webpage only in that i am using flot.js to display some bar graphs , it is working fien if the number of bars  is less than 10 but if it contains more than that, it is not showing all the bars that it is supposed to show